# What is a better ActiveRecord query for this scenario

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm getting my result but I feel all dirty inside.

How can I better get the closest pay_rate or home_base_assignment start_date that is the earlier than or equal to a given date?

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home_base_assignments
  has_many :position_assignments
  has_many :pay_rates, :through => :position_assignments

  def closest_prior_assignment_start(date)
    closest_prior_pay_rate_start = 
      pay_rates.where("pay_rates.start_date <= ?", date)
    .order(:start_date).last.start_date

    closest_prior_home_base_start =
      home_base_assignments.where("start_date <= ?", date)
        .order(:start_date).last.start_date

    [closest_prior_pay_rate_start, closest_prior_home_base_start].sort!.last
  end
end
```

*Yuck!*

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your methods a bit using scope, here's something I think you add to your model:

```
scope :lastest, order("start_date DESC")

closest_prior_pay_rate_start = 
  pay_rates.where("pay_rates.start_date <= ?", date).latest

closest_prior_home_base_start =
  home_base_assignments.where("start_date <= ?", date).latest
```

Comment: Thanks. For sure this would be a good idea, but the code I've posted is just to explain the problem mostly. I think the real issue is how to avoid two queries and the use of the Ruby array, surely there is a single query solution.